# Working with cache memory. Mapping techniques

Tags: c++, c, caching, computer-science

I am taking at my university a course of Computer Arhitecture. I have a little problem with the cache mapping subject.

Let's say i have a code like this

```
for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
for (int j=0;j<256;j++)
    a[i*1024+j] = i+j
```

My RAM size is 64kb, cache size is 2kb and the size of a block is 256b.
First step is to find how many block I have in cache and in RAM. After computation I get 256 blocks in RAM and 8 blocks in cache. I find the adresses format (Tag|Index|Offset)for cache for every mapping technics : direct, associative and set associative and I need to find the miss cache based on that code and compute the acces time to find wich mapping technics is better. Here I get stucked because I need to see what is the content of RAM and the content of cache.

Comment: I don't see any information about virtual addresses here. Caches and virtual addressing are independent features. For the rest: Not enough information And: what is the question?

Comment: Giving that code i need to compute the miss-cache and the time needed to accces the memory.

Comment: This is neither a coding, nor a consulting service. See [ask].

Comment: You can't compute miss-cache and time to access memory given this code.

Comment: Why not? That code generates a sequence of numbers at every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate the working of cache and RAM as follows:

Start by having a int(4 bytes) array  `int a[16][64]`. Now, assume that array starts from memory location `0`. So by having such an array you can see that all the rows a[0], a[1],...a[15] each having 64 columns. Now `array a` is 2D i.e array of array. Also, you can see that all the 64 elements of each row can be placed in a block of size 256 (64*sizeof(int)) directly.

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    for(j = 0; j < 64; ++j)
        a[i][j] = i+j;
```

Now in the above code you are trying to access the elements of array in row wise 
manner from top to bottom. Now assume that array is in RAM and your cache which has 8 blocks and which can accommodate 64 ints is completely empty.

Now on accessing `a[0][0]` miss will occur in cache and a block will be brought from RAM into cache. Now, if you should notice that miss will not occur while accessing elements a[0][k] (1 <= k <= 63) because all the elements  can be served from cache.

Now on accessing `a[1][0]` again a miss will occur and the corresponding block will be brought from RAM to cache and so forth.

On accessing a[8][0] you should find that a miss has occurred and the cache is full and now some block needs to be replaced with new block from RAM (replacement algorithm will depend upon the cache mapping method that is used).

In this way you can simulate hit and miss for different cache mapping techniques.

If you understood this then access time can also be found depending upon how much was hit rate and miss rate (or number of hits and miss).